# Get dynamic params created from new ol.source.ImageWMS

Tags: openlayers-3

According to [this documentation of ol3](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html) the params option of WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and CRS (SRS for WMS version < 1.3.0) will be set dynamically.

How can someone retrieve this information? Get for example the BBOX of the image in map coordinates.?

**Update**:
When I use your code though in mine i get a NaN value

```
        var lay = new ol.layer.Image({
            extent: transform,
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                url: Layers.link,
                params: {'LAYERS': Layers.name},
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
                    image.getImage().src = src;
                    // parse src for whatever you want to know
                    var bbox = src.match(/BBOX\=([^&^#]*)/)[1].split(',').map(Number);
                    console.log(bbox)
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: Maybe your src also has a NaN in the BBOX? Check with `console.log(src)`. Why do you want to know the requested BBOX in the first place?

Comment: I need to get the bounding box of the layer which is georeferenced in the map of openlayers with the default epsg:3857 without get it reproject from one coordinate system to another. I make the request with a different  crs but the openlayers translate it with the epsg:3857 which is the default. I assume that it makes the transformation automatically

Comment: Also when i try console.log(src) i get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: scr is not defined

Comment: Check for typos - src vs. scr.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/180615/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this information for debugging only, you will find it in your browser's developer tools by looking at the WMS requests that get sent:
[image: Chrome Developer Tools Network pane]

If you need this information in your application, you can define a custom `imageLoadFunction` on your ImageWMS source to inspect the requested URL:

```
new ol.source.ImageWMS({
  // ...
  imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
    image.getImage().src = src;
    // parse src for whatever you want to know
    var bbox = src.match(/BBOX\=([^&^#]*)/)[1].split(',').map(Number);
  }
});
```

Comment: the bbox returns NaN when i add this code into mine. check my update in question for the code